# pdf of a random variable involving distances

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n$ be n points on the unit segment $[0,1]$.Let $X$ be a uniformly and randomly chosen point in  $\in[0,1]$ and  $$Y= \Bigg|\frac1n \sum_1^n|X-x_i|-\frac12 \Bigg |.$$ Is it psossible to find the pdf of  $Y.$Thank you for any hints/suggestions in advance.

Comment: Should it be $X$ instead of $x$ in the sum? And I assume you want the sum to go from 1 and not from 0?

Comment: Yes indeed.thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I think, as least as far as I can see, that it's quite hard to explicitly write down the PDF for some $n$ because of the absolute values. You could probably say something about the asymptotic behavior though.

Comment: Coonection with the median of the $a_i$ ; https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2369394

Comment: The pdf of random variable $Z:= \sum_{1}^n|X-x_i|$ looks obtainable. Knowing it, it should be easy to get the pdf of $Y$. Are you always interested by this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give here an important intermediate result. Up to you to use it for reaching the final objective.

The set of $n$ values $x_i$ being fixed ($n$ being assumed an odd integer), Let us in a first step define the function

$$f(x):= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^n|c-x_i|$$

(see the graph of such a function on the left of the following figure ; the abscissa of the minimum is the **median** of values $x_i$). Let us now define the random variable

$$Z=f(U), \ \ \ \ U \sim Unif(0,1)$$

The pdf of $Z$ has the shape of a decreasing staircase as can be seen on the right hand part of the figure which represents a histogram (materialized by little circles) of the values taken by $Z$ in a large scale simulation (you can consult as well the Matlab program having generated the left and right figure below).

The reason is that this pdf is the sum of $n+1$ weighted characteristic functions of intervals to be found on the axis of ordinates of the first figure, colors having been chosen in order that one can retrieve on the right figure the origin of these characteristic functions on the left figure.

I will stop my explanations here, waiting for the OP to say if he/she has understood the origin of the different "characters" leading to the result.

Remark: in the case where the number of points is even, function $f$ has a "plateau" instead of a peaky minimum. As a consequence, the pdf of $Z$ has a staircase shape, like above, to which must be added a $\delta$ function.

[image]

Matlab program:

```
clear all;close all;hold on;
LS='linesmoothing';LW='linewidth';
A=[0.12,0.18,0.55,0.68,0.9];
n=length(A);
f=@(x)(sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,x'*ones(1,5),A)),2));
x=0:0.01:1;
figure(1);set(gcf,'color','w');plot(x,f(x)/n,LS,'on',LW,1);
col=rand(n+1,3);% colors' table
B=[0,A,1];C=f(B)/n;
for k=1:n+1;
    plot(B(k:k+1),C(k:k+1),'color',col(k,:),LS,'on',LW,3);
end;
m=3000000;x=rand(1,m);
figure(2);hold on;set(gcf,'color','w');
[U,V]=hist(f(x)/n,100);
scatter(V,U/m);
for k=1:n+1;
    h=(B(k+1)-B(k))/(abs(C(k)-C(k+1))*85*n);
    plot([C(k),C(k+1)],h*[1,1],'color',col(k,:),LW,3);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful response.I myself had done a similar thing in python and for large number of sample points I got something like a parabola.I will add my code and figure to the question.However,that is still far from any clue as to how we can find the pdf of Y.I wonder   of somehow we can find the  pdf of one term that is $|X-c|$,could  we somehow find the pdf of the sum then?

Comment: See a former answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4150515)